# Batch script not working, results different from code provided

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

**Explanation**

I have a folder labeled MAP with around 15,103 sub-folders (all with there own unique name).

Inside each of these sub-folders contain another sub-folder with the exact same name as its parent folder.

Inside the final sub-folder contains an image called miniMap.canvas.png

Here is an example of the path.

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\000010000.img\000010000.img\miniMap.canvas.png

And here is what I want;

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\000010000.img\miniMap.canvas.png

Also, some of the sub-folders do not contain a .png, therefore I would just want the two folders merged for the outcome;

C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\000020000.img\

**Batch**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /S /B "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\*"') do (
    for %%y in ("%%a\*.png") do (
        call :GETPARENTPARENT "%%y" ret
        echo ret=!ret!
        move /Y "%%y" "!ret!"
      rd %%a
    )
)
goto:EOF

:GETPARENTPARENT
set fileP=%1
echo received=%fileP%
for %%a in (%fileP%) do (
    set parent=%%~dpa
    cd !parent!\..
    set PPPath=!cd!
    for %%x in ("!PPPath!") do (
        set "%~2=%%~dpnx"
    )
)
goto:EOF
```

**Results**

The results are really interesting in the picture provided.

As you can see, folders that contained a image were merged; however, they were empty! Folders that did not contain a image were not merged! Lastly, instead of each image being in its respected folder, it created "files" outside of the folders, thus destroying the images and not placing them in there unique folders.

PLS HELP.

EDIT: Also I do have a backup of the folder MAP, lol.

[image: result]

Comment: The nested for runs "dir" in the same directory as the first dir.
It will run against all subdirs, including MAP\000010000.img and MAP\000010000.img\000010000.img.

Nesting "for" statements in a BATCH I have found to be tricky - I always avoid it.

The answer by unclemeat looks OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you ask -

```
set root=C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP
for /f %%a in ('dir /B /AD %root%') do if exist "%root%\%%a\%%a\miniMap.canvas.png" (
    move "%root%\%%a\%%a\miniMap.canvas.png" "%root%\%%a"
    rmdir "%root%\%%a\%%a"
)
```

it loops through the main directory and checks if the `miniMap.canvas.png` file exists in the specified sub directory and moves it up a directory if necessary, then deletes the extra directory.

Comment: For some reason it did not delete any extra directory that was empty...for example; C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\001000001.img\001000001.img was not changed to: C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\MAP\001000001.img ; HOWEVER, the rest of the intended function worked!

Comment: @Andrew that is strange. Are you saying it only didn't delete that example you gave, or that it didn't delete all of the repeated directories?

Comment: Doesn't matter unclemeat, your script is working perfectly and the issue was solved by me through the uploading to my server.